# Create an ODBC connection using Windows NT Authentication with a specific user

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-7, odbc

Is it possible to create an SQL ODBC connection in Windows 7 that uses Windows NT Authentication but for a specific user such that any user can use the ODBC connection as that pre-defined account?

For example, can I create an SQL ODBC connection to use Windows NT Authentication through `company\someSpecificID` such that even if `company\user1` uses the ODBC connection (like through MS Access) then the connection will use `company\someSpecificID` (even though `company\user1` is logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add user and pass in the connection string?

To test connection string you can create in your desktop a file (right clic -> new-> .txt) and **save it like `.udl` extension**. Now open it and you can configure a connection with differents parameters, and you can test it!.

if you are trying to use Windows Authentication with different user... the only way i could find was with "runas" command, in this link you have answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348517/how-i-can-authenticate-in-sql-server-2008-with-active-directory-user-but-without)

hope this help!